# ResGen.exe stucks when redirect output

Tags: c#, process

I try to redirect standard output from ResGen.exe. I use following code

```
ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo( "resxGen.exe" );
psi.CreateNoWindow = true;
psi.Arguments = sb.ToString();
psi.UseShellExecute = false;
psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
Process p = Process.Start( psi );
p.WaitForExit();
StreamReader sr = p.StandardOutput;
string message = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
```

It stuck on p.WaitForExit. When I turn off output stream redirection and do not read StandardOutput it works correctly.

What do I do wrong ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would need to wait for the process to end after reading the stream, otherwise you have a deadlock in your code.
The problem is that your parent process is blocking waiting for the child process to finish, and the child process is waiting for the parent process to read the output, hence you have a deadlock.

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandardoutput.aspx) is a good and detailed description of the problem.

Changing your code like this should avoid the deadlock:

```
StreamReader sr = p.StandardOutput;
string message = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
p.WaitForExit();
```

Comment: Yup.  Read the output, not "write to the output".  The output buffer is small, 2 kilobytes is typical.  ReadToEnd before WaitForExit is good enough, the "end" doesn't happen until the program ends.

Comment: Thanks. The problem gets a bit more complicated though if you need to write the output of the app real time to a UI for example, this won't solve that.

Answer (score 1):

The bottom line would seem to be that the placement of `p.WaitForExit`is incorrect; this method call should be made only after reading what you want from the stream.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandardoutput.aspx):

```
 // Start the child process.
 Process p = new Process();
 // Redirect the output stream of the child process.
 p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
 p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
 p.StartInfo.FileName = "Write500Lines.exe";
 p.Start();
 // Do not wait for the child process to exit before
 // reading to the end of its redirected stream.
 // p.WaitForExit();
 // Read the output stream first and then wait.
 string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
 p.WaitForExit();
```

Also note that your use of `StreamReader sr = p.StandardOutput` is redundant here since when the value of`message` is set you access the stream using `p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();` - note the **`p.StandardOutput`** as opposed to **`sr.ReadToEnd()`**.