# Proper way to run PsList.exe from my C# app and get its output (Or why my code doesn't work)?

Tags: c#, exe, external-application

Why this code only shows cmd window and never reaches the end ? I want to get the output from PsList into my C# app.
Execution halts on this line: "int exitCode = proc.ExitCode;"

```
private static void PsList()
{           
    ProcessStartInfo start = new ProcessStartInfo();            
    start.FileName = @"C:\PsList.exe";
    start.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
    start.CreateNoWindow = true;
    start.UseShellExecute = false;
    start.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

    using (Process proc = Process.Start(start))
    {
        proc.WaitForExit(4000);

        int exitCode = proc.ExitCode;
        string exitMsg = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
    }
}
```

Comment: It is waiting for you to read its output.

Comment: Thank you very much. I see the error now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might try rearranging things a bit:

```
using (Process proc = Process.Start(start))
{
    string exitMsg = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
    proc.WaitForExit(4000);

    int exitCode = proc.ExitCode;
}
```

There are many related questions such as [How to get log from Process.Start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3296601/how-to-get-log-from-process-start) and [ResGen.exe stucks when redirect output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5365449/resgen-exe-stucks-when-redirect-output)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how exactly the execution halts on the proc.ExitCode line, it may be the process isn't finished by the time the ExitCode property is accessed, and then it will throw a InvalidOperationException.

In that case you could check if the process has already exited with proc.HasExited before trying to access the ExitCode property